# Access service from Angular component test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am testing my component and did not want to have to create a mock service so instead I injected the real service.  I wanted to spy on one of the service's functions in a test but was getting a Typescript error: `argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`.

**Is there a correct way of doing this without mocking the entire service?**

```
describe('DocumentsPage', () => {
  let component: DocumentsPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DocumentsPage>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DocumentsPage ],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        ClientDocService
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DocumentsPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('loadClientDocuments', () => {
    it('should call clientDocService.fetchClientAndSignedDocuments', () => {

      // This is the error
      const spy = spyOn(ClientDocService, 'fetchClientAndSignedDocuments')

      component.loadClientDocuments()
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
});
```

Here's the function:

```
fetchClientDocs( clientId : number, updateDocs: boolean = true ) : Observable<IClientDoc[]> {
    const url = `${this.base_url}/clients/${clientId}/client_docs`
    return this.http.get<IClientDoc[]>(url).pipe(
      tap( clientDocs => {
        clientDocs.forEach(doc => {
          doc.fileKey = decodeURIComponent(doc.fileKey)
        })

        if (updateDocs) {
          this.setClientDocs(clientDocs)
          this.setMergedDocuments([], clientDocs)
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: If you want to go that route, try `spyOn(ClientDocService.prototype, 'fetchClientAndSignedDocuments')`.  Though I would use `TestBed.inject` to get the instance and spy on that directly `const service = TestBed.inject(ClientDocService);`

Comment: Do I remove `ClientDocService` from the providers array in that scenario?  When I run the tests it says `NullInjectorError: No provider for ClientDocService!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like `possum` mentioned, I would use `TestBed.inject` to get a handle on the service.

```
it('should call clientDocService.fetchClientAndSignedDocuments', () => {
      // !! Get a handle on the service
      const clientDocService = TestBed.inject(ClientDocService);
      // !! spy on the one we have
      const spy = spyOn(clientDocService, 'fetchClientAndSignedDocuments')

      component.loadClientDocuments()
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
```

Comment: In this scenario do you leave `ClientDocService` out of the providers array?

Comment: I would keep it. I am thinking if it is `providedIn: 'root'`, Angular will know where to get the service from but I am not totally sure. I say keep it because it becomes explicit in the TestBed module that you depend on this service. Also, I don't think `TestBed.inject` would work if it's not included in the providers array.